# mongodb aggregate lookup multiple ObjectId in object

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections and I have a collection data in MongoDB

```
db.user.insert({"_id" : ObjectId("585d627fe4ff58cb1c456780"), "name":"Alfred"});
db.user.insert({"_id" : ObjectId("585d60b5e4ff58cb1c45677f"), "name":"Bruce"});
db.role.insert({"_id" : ObjectId("585d5f7cdb83cb696b82f2cf"),"status" : "admin"});
db.data.insert(
"security": [
    {"idUser" : ObjectId("585d627fe4ff58cb1c456780"), "idRole" : ObjectId("585d5f7cdb83cb696b82f2cf")},
    {"idUser" : ObjectId("585d60b5e4ff58cb1c45677f"), "idRole" : ObjectId("585d5f7cdb83cb696b82f2cf") }]);
```

When I execute this condition the array returns empty

```
db.data.aggregate([
            { $lookup: {from: "user", localField: "user.idUser", foreignField: "_id", as: "user_admin"} },
            {$unwind:"$user_admin"},
]);
```

I wanted to bring the two populated fields with the attributes of each object in the array, I am very grateful to anyone who helps me

Comment: This correct

db.data.aggregate([
            { $lookup: {from: "user", localField: "security.idUser", foreignField: "_id", as: "user_admin"} },
            {$unwind:"$user_admin"},
]);

Answer (score 0):

In order to aggregate over security, you need to unwind it and then lookup. This query should work:

```
db.data.aggregate([
            {$unwind: "$security"},
            {$lookup: {from: "user", localField: "security.idUser", foreignField: "_id", as: "user_admin"}},
            {$unwind:"$user_admin"}
]);
```

Comment: It returns only the first element of the array, it does not bring the other elements